# How to add 0 to string column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a string column that is missing leading 0's. An example of this is

```
9/14/2006 4:5:19 PM
```

It should have a 0 to make it `09/14/2006 4:05:19 PM`

Comment: DATETIME columns don't contain strings, they contain an internal representation of the time. Zeroes come from the code you use to format it. How are you printing the date/time?

Comment: If you're worried about the format of a date value in the database, [you're doing dates very wrong.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/07/13/sql-and-dates/)

Comment: It's an existing string column in a database - I don't want to do anything with what was already created just create my own new column with leading 0's for those items

Comment: If you're stuck with the broken schema (because a schema with date values in a string column really is _broken_ and needs to be fixed) and you're creating your own column, then create the column **right**, as a datetime, and not **wrong**, as just another poorly-formatted string that will not index properly or work with existing date functions.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: I guess the core thing to understand here is the values in this column are **NOT TIMESTAMPS!!** They are string values that merely kinda/sorta look like timestamps, but that is not the same thing. As such this is going to be slower... MUCH slower... and harder to work with than a correct (because this really is _incorrect_) design with a datetime column.

Comment: Additionally, _if_ you are stuck with using a string column in the schema, at very least format the string column so the elements in the date come in a consistent, _sortable_ order from greatest to least: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.fff]`

Comment: `update mysterytablename set mysterycolumnname=concat('0',mysterycolumnname) where mysterycolumnname like '_/%'`

Comment: wait, why are you adding a zero to the month and minute but not the hour?

Comment: @ysth because it's PM

Comment: that would make sense if there were only hours up to 9 :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to do anything with what was already created just create
> my own new column with leading 0's for those items

You can create your column with proper date datatype, it will be much easier to query and format the date as you wish

Use str_to_date to convert string to date

```
select str_to_date(my_dt,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p') 
from test;
```

Then update the newly created column :

```
update test 
set correct_dt = str_to_date(my_dt,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p');
```

You can find all the steps above in the fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b53020805776571c7c9f644eb94123c